# Connecting two points defined in two different axis combined with addplot3

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

I want to draw something like the following code where I try to connect two different points which are defined in two different axis. I use `addplot3` to draw 3D surfaces.
However, when I try to connect these points, the connecting line shows somewhere else. There is a problem with coordinates. I'm confused. Of course, if I draw all surfaces using just one axis, then I don't have a problem. The reason why I use several axis is that I want to use different `mesh/interior colormap` for the interior. If I use just one axis, then I will get completely different result.

What is my mistake here? I think I don't understand something about coordinate well.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 declare function={
f(\x,\y)=-exp(-2*(\x^4+\y^4));
}]

\begin{axis}[
view={40}{15},
mesh/interior colormap name=viridis,
hide axis,
xmin=-6, xmax=6,
ymin=-6, ymax=6,
zmin=-6, zmax=6,
]
\addplot3[  
surf,
samples=30,
samples y=20,
] {f(\x+1,\y)+2};

\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
view={40}{15},
mesh/interior colormap name=viridis,
hide axis,
xmin=-6, xmax=6,
ymin=-6, ymax=6,
zmin=-6, zmax=6,
]
\addplot3[  
surf,
samples=30,
samples y=20,
] {f(\x+1,\y)-1};

\addplot3 coordinates {(1,3,1)} coordinate [alias=c2];

\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
view={40}{15},
mesh/interior colormap name=viridis,
hide axis,
xmin=-6, xmax=6,
ymin=-6, ymax=6,
zmin=-6, zmax=6,
]

\addplot3[
  surf,
  faceted color=blue,
  hide axis,
  fill=gray,
  samples=30,
  samples y=20,
] {-4};

\addplot3 [only marks, mark = *, mark size = 3pt, mark options={fill=red}]
coordinates {(-1,0,-4)} coordinate [alias=c1];

  \draw[thick, -stealth] (c1) -- (c2);

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: When asking questions, you shoud construct a compilable MWE. Please see: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: There is no reason to start a new `axis` here. The only difference is how point meta is scaled. You can ask a new question about that - post MWE, picture of your current output with one axis and your desired output.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for MWE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={f(\x,\y)=-exp(-2*(\x^4+\y^4));},
]
\begin{axis}[
view={40}{15},
mesh/interior colormap name=viridis,
hide axis,
xmin=-6, xmax=6,
ymin=-6, ymax=6,
zmin=-6, zmax=6,
]
\addplot3[  
surf,
samples=30,
samples y=20,
] {f(\x+1,\y)+2};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
view={40}{15},
mesh/interior colormap name=viridis,
hide axis,
xmin=-6, xmax=6,
ymin=-6, ymax=6,
zmin=-6, zmax=6,
]
\addplot3[  
surf,
samples=30,
samples y=20,
] {f(\x+1,\y)-1};
\addplot3 coordinates {(1,3,1)} coordinate (c2);
\coordinate (c2) at (1,3,1);
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
view={40}{15},
mesh/interior colormap name=viridis,
hide axis,
xmin=-6, xmax=6,
ymin=-6, ymax=6,
zmin=-6, zmax=6,
]
\addplot3[
surf,
faceted color=blue,
hide axis,
fill=gray,
samples=30,
samples y=20,
] {-4};
\addplot3 [only marks, mark = *, mark size = 3pt, mark options={fill=red}]
coordinates {(-1,0,-4)} coordinate (c1);
\end{axis}
\draw[thick, -stealth] (c1) -- (c2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Three plenes with an arrow between two points]

*Edit:* Here is the structure of the above code in a MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-6, xmax=6, ymin=-6, ymax=6, zmin=-6, zmax=6,]
\coordinate (c2) at (1,3,1); %one coordinate
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-6, xmax=6, ymin=-6, ymax=6, zmin=-6, zmax=6,]
\coordinate (c1) at (-1,0,-4); %an other coordinate
\end{axis}
\draw[thick, -stealth] (c1) -- (c2); %connecting the two coordinates
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this? Also on your comment that there is no need for extra axis? If I don't use extra axis then interior colormap gives unreasonable results...

Comment: You have two very different questions. I have only answered the one in the title. You could ask a new question about the "unreasonable results", but you need to describe or show pictures of these results.